# Setting float for blend tree?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm currently creating a third person controller based on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwD1UHNCzOc&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0djuNM22htmz3BUtHHtOh7v&index=7) and I'm trying to expand the third person controller with extra functions like pushing objects. The third person controller doesn't have a rigidbody or anything since it is using a CharacterController component. I have created a raycast in front of the player that checks if the object in front of the player is a pushable, which is working fine. When the object in front of the player is a pushable, the bool isPushing in the animator is set to true and the Animator goes to a blend tree. This blendtree consist out of 2 animations; idlePushAnimation and a walkingPushAnimation, those are controlled by a float "speedPercentPush". This is where I get stuck. How can I make it so that when the player is not moving in the pushing state the float is set to "0" and when the CharacterController is moving in the pushing state the float is set to "1"?

In the end I'm looking for something like:

```
anim.SetFloat("speedPercentPush", I think this should be something like either 0 or 1, speedSmoothTime, Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Can you post a picture of the blendtree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the **horizontal speed** of the `CharacterController` and assign it to the `blend tree` float value like this:

```js
public CharacterController controller;
    Vector3 horizontalVelocity = controller.velocity;
    float horizontalSpeed;

    void Update() {
      if(isPushing){
         controller.setBool("isPushing",true);
         horizontalVelocity = new Vector3(controller.velocity.x, 0, controller.velocity.z);
         horizontalSpeed = horizontalVelocity.magnitude;
         controller.setFloat("speedPercentPush",horizontalSpeed );
      }else{
         controller.setFloat("speedPercentPush",0);
         controller.setBool("isPushing",false);
      }
    }
```

Also, first check around what horizontal speed, you want to make the transition from **idlePushAnimation** to **walkingPushAnimation** and set the `blend tree` parameter's `threshold` accordingly.
You can have a look at this tutorial to know more about `blend trees`:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HeHvlEYpRbM

Comment: I was working with something similar last night but still had issues with the animations and when they are played. Last night I was checking controller.velocity != Vector3.zero and it was kind of working, I have to say I wasn’t using a blendtree at that time. The issue though is that when the player was idlePushing if you turned away from the pushable object it will always go to the walkingPushing animation because there is movement. This is when I realised I need a blend tree, but also another check if the movement is towards the pushable object.

Comment: What I’m trying to say is that your solution is the right one, but it needs a couple of more checks I think. I think it should be checking if the movement is towards the Pushable object and when there is velocity towards that object the float speedPercentPushing should be “1”, if there is no movement towards that object it should be “0”. How would I add in the extra check? And currently your solution is checking only the x axis, but the game is 3d, should it not also check the z axis?

Comment: Sorry totally missed the z check, I see now. So there should be one more check if the player is moving in the direction of the pushable object and the float should be set to 1 when this is true.

Comment: In your question you said, you have already checked through raycast about the moving direction. So, you can give one more check inside the update function using a bool. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: I think I now understand how to appoach this, will give it a go later today when I get home from work and keep you updated! Thanks for explaining thusfar :)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I finally got it to work. Another important thing I found out was setting the treshold on the animations within the blendtree.